# ListViewrenderRow or bind(this) not working with ListView give me results blank

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-listview

Here is my code which is not working ...
I want to show User name but my app give me Blank info I am new if you get any wrong on my Question please comment and sorry for my bad English .

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {AppRegistry, ListView, Text, View, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
const users = [
  { name: 'John Doe'},
  { name: 'Brad Traversy'},
  { name: 'Steve Smith'},
  { name: 'Janet Williams'},
  { name: 'Ashik Billa'}


];

export default class Component4 extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        const ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
        this.state = {
            userDataSource: ds.cloneWithRows([users]),
        };
    }

    renderRow(user, sectionId, rowId, highlightRow) {
        console.log(user.name);
        return (
            <View>
                <Text>{user.name}</Text>
            </View>

        )
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <ListView
                dataSource={this.state.userDataSource}
                renderRow={this.renderRow.bind(this)}
            />
        );
    }
}


AppRegistry.registerComponent('Component4', () => Component4);
```

**Also** `console.log(user.name);` Show Undefined and have **anyway** to get ? .

Answer (score 1):

```
export default class Component4 extends Component {
constructor() {
    super();
    const ds = new ListView.DataSource({ rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2 });
    this.state = {
        userDataSource: ds.cloneWithRows([users]),
    };
}

render() {
    return (
        <ListView
            dataSource={this.state.userDataSource}
            renderRow={(user) => <Text>{user}</Text>}
        />
    );
}
```

}

This code should snippet should give you an idea of how to use the ListView component.

Comment: Thanks for yours answer but right I was change my code stell it's not working ... 
Also I am not understand how can I get " pass the correct data in here"" ?
how can i can my **users** array

Comment: I would imagine that you have the users array on state or props. Simply take that array of users and pass in to the renerRow function. It would be just like any other function that is declared expecting arguments, and invoked with those arguments passed in. Fairly certain that once you do that your issue will be solved.

Comment: excellently, I can't cache the point if you chnage my code it will be batter answer for me. 
I am going to request you can you chnage the code the make it right code for Output :)

Comment: I am actually not 100% clear with the ListView component since it is specific to react-native, but this resource should help you get an idea. https://medium.com/differential/react-native-basics-how-to-use-the-listview-component-a0ec44cf1fe8

Comment: Yes, Now i am understand what you was say, this code missing **bind** think i was need is ,,,,
Also right now i am getting erro .......`Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {key, name}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an
 array instead or wrap the object using createFragment(object) from the React add-ons.
`

Answer (score 0):

First, you should declare the datasource in the constructor like so

`this.ds = new ListView.DataSource({ rowHasChanged: (r1,r2) => r1 !== r2 })`

This line is wrong `ds.cloneWithRows([users])` as users is already an array.

It should be `this.ds.cloneWithRows(users)`

Here is your fixed code

```
constructor() {
    super()
    this.ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2})
    this.state = {
      userDataSource: this.ds.cloneWithRows(users)
    }
  }

  renderRow = (user, sectionId, rowId, highlightRow) => {
    console.log(user.name)
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>{ user.name }</Text>
      </View>

    )
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ListView
        dataSource={ this.state.userDataSource }
        renderRow={ this.renderRow }
      />
    )
  }
```